# How to load JPEG as a BITMAP from server using Picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, remote-server, picasso

I've tried using the method:

```
bmp = (Bitmap) Picasso.with(Feed.this).load(IMAGE_URL+loadImageUrl).resize(width, width).get();
```

But I get a "Picasso DownloadResponseException" even when I take out the (Bitmap) typeCast

I've also tried:

```
Picasso.with(Feed.this).load(IMAGE_URL+image).resize(width, width).into(target);
```

With

```
private Target target = new Target() {

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("FAILED", "Bitmap Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bmp, LoadedFrom arg1) {

        RoundedCornersDrawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
        theImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    }
};
```

But it gives me nothing, the image doesn't load it just stays blank and the log message under the BitmapFailed method does not come up... The images stored on my server are of type "jpg".

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out I had the wrong URL. Also make sure you Don't call that Picasso.get() method inside the UI thread...